# Calling python script (that uses subprocess to call grep) from sub-directory causes error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm calling grep via a python script, and storing the output into a list. I only want `grep` to search files with specific file extensions, i.e. .c, .cpp, and  .h. I'm using the function `subprocess.check_output()`

(grep_pattern.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
grep_str = subprocess.check_output(['grep', 'rl', '--include=*.{c,cpp,h}', 'pattern', '.'])
print grep_str
```

The code works fine when I call grep_pattern.py from the same directory, i.e. `./grep_pattern` or from any directories above it, e.g. `./scripts/python/grep_pattern.py`, or `./python/grep_pattern.py`. However, the code returns the following error if I call it from any directory below it, e.g. `../grep_pattern.py` or `../../grep_pattern.py`

```
File "./grep_include.py", line 7, in <module>
  ls_output_str = subprocess.check_output(['grep', '-rl', '--include=*.{c,cpp,h}', 'pattern', '.'])
File "/<path>/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
  raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['grep', '-rl', '--include=*.{c,cpp,h}', 'pattern', '/projects/<path>/APACHE\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

What's strange is if I remove the `'--include=*.{c,cpp,h}'` option, the code works regardless of where it is called from.

Comment: When you have a shell, `--include=*.{c,cpp,}` is split into three separate arguments: `--include=*.c`, `--include=*.cpp` and `--include=*.`. There's no shell here, so you need to do that yourself.

Comment: Also, `rl` vs `-rl` looks like a typo. Actually, it clearly *is* a typo, since the dash is there in your exception.

Comment: your first comment did the trick, thanks!

Also you're right about using strip() & the typo. It should be -rl, not r1

Comment: No need to edit a solution into the answer -- clicking the checkbox suffices. (Part of why we prefer that approach is that if someone posted a *better* answer later, theirs could be voted up and mine could be voted down -- but an answer that's edited into the question has "special status", inasmuch as it can't be voted on without voting on the question itself).

Comment: (...and if I had *only* commented, and not left an answer, but you wanted to accept that comment as an answer, what you can do is add an answer with the information from the comment yourself -- it's polite, but not required, to mark "Community Wiki" for an answer that's using someone else's content; but all that the rules strictly require in that respect is attribution).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces aren't part of pattern-match syntax, and `grep`'s `--include` and `--exclude` arguments don't handle them. Instead, they're an instruction **to the shell** to create several variants of the argument/word in which they exist. You have no shell here, so nothing is honoring these instructions.

Expanding them out might look as follows:

```
grep_str = subprocess.check_output(
    ['grep', '-rl',
     '--include=*.c',
     '--include=*.cpp',
     '--include=*.h',
     'pattern', '.'])
```

With this done, the `--include` pattern will actually be able to match filenames that exist on your disk, such that your `grep` call might be able to successfully find a match for the pattern, at which point it can return a result of success.

---

By the way -- the `\n` on the end of the path given in your exception is a bit of a red flag. Unless you *actually* have a directory name ending in a literal newline (which is possible, but rare), ensure that you're properly stripping trailing newlines when received from `readline()` or similar.